# Accessing a specific item in a multidimensional array in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get the 0 index of a nested array in a multidimensional array. I'm using a foreach binding that lists the states and cities to a `<ul>`. My current code is:

http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/vNMKzg?editors=101

```
<ul id='list' data-bind="foreach: states">
<li>
    <div>Surf locations in
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>:
    </div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: city">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data"> </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>


var state = function(name, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = ko.observableArray(city);
}
var viewModel = {
    states: [
        new state("Virginia", [["Va Beach",[36.852926, -75.977985]], ["Chincoteague Island",[37.933179, -75.378809]]]),
        new state("Maryland", [["Atlantic City",[39.364283, -74.422927]], ["Ocean city",[38.336503, -75.084906]]]),
        new state("North Carolina", [["Oakacroke",[35.114615, -75.98101]], ["Nags Head",[35.957392, -75.624062]],["Emerald Isle",[34.677940, -76.950776]]])
        ]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

My current code is showing the lon, lat and the city names, but I only want list the city names tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array indexers in your bindings, so you can access the first index with `$data[0]`:

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: city">
     <li>
         <span data-bind="text: $data[0]"> </span>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKZppR)

A more view model oriented approach would be to create a proper "city" object which has a `name` property:

```
var City = function(data) {
  this.name = data[0];
  this.coords = data[1];
}
```

And use this `City` when creating a `state`:

```
var state = function(name, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = ko.observableArray(city.map(function(c){ return new City(c)}));
}
```

And your binding could look like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: city">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Sample [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQWdMW)

Comment: Wow. I would have sworn I tried that already. It works, thanks. I'll accept your answer asap.